# Consulta por rendimiento al importar función o clase con mss()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una duda si me pudieran ayudar u orientar ya que estoy aprendiendo sobre programación de forma autodidacta y es que cuando hago funcionar mss desde el propio fichero **test.py** dentro de un **ciclo for** o **while** en el que éste está escrito, obtiene un rendimiento de aproximadamente 98 fps. El código es sencillo:

**test.py**

```
from time import time
from mss.linux import MSS as mss
from numpy import asarray

lista = []
loop_time = time()
with mss() as sct:
    for _ in range(1000):
        sct_img = sct.grab(sct.monitors[1])
        sct_img = asarray(sct_img)
        lista.append(1 / (time() - loop_time))
        loop_time = time()
```

Pero cuando lo meto dentro de una función **capturar()** en el mismo archivo **test.py**, por ejemplo, este baja inmediatamente a 38 fps promedio, sea **con with** o **sin with**. Y cuando lo llamo desde otro archivo, en este caso **main.py**, baja al rango de los 27 fps.

**test.py con python-mss inserto dentro de una función**

```
from time import time
from mss.linux import MSS as mss
from numpy import asarray


def capturar():
    sct_img = sct.grab(sct.monitors[1])
    return asarray(sct_img)

lista = []
loop_time = time()
for _ in range(1000):
    img = capturar()
    lista.append(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
    loop_time = time()
```

Cuando lo voy a importar, borro todo y sólo dejo la función en sí.

En **main.py** lo que hay es un bucle **for** o **while** sencillamente, llamando a la función **capturar()** desde **test.py**

**main.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
from test import capturar
# from test2 import Capturador
from pathlib import Path
from os import chdir, path
from time import time

chdir(path.dirname(Path(__file__).absolute()))

# cap = Capturador()
lista = []
loop_time = time()
for _ in range(1000):
    img = capturar()
    lista.append(1 / (time() - loop_time))
    loop_time = time()
```

En cambio, cuando lo programo de la siguiente forma (novato) en el archivo **test2.py**:

**test2.py**

```
from time import time
from mss.linux import MSS as mss
from numpy import asarray



class Capturador:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sct = mss()

    def capturador(self):
        self.arriba = 0
        self.izquierda = 0
        self.ancho = 1365
        self.alto = 768
        self.monitor = {"top": self.arriba,
                    "left": self.izquierda,
                    "width": self.ancho,
                    "height": self.alto}
        image = self.sct.grab(self.monitor)
        return asarray(image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Capturador()
```

Obtengo un rendimiento de 88 fps llamando a la clase **Capturador()** también dentro de un ciclo **for** o **while** en el mismo archivo **test2.py** , pero cuando lo importo a otro archivo, en este caso a **main.py**, aumenta a un rango de 138 fps y elimino todo el código después de **if **name** == '**main**'**, dejando solo Capturador().

¿A qué se debe este comportamiento, es esperable, por qué en el primer caso disminuye y en el segundo aumenta, cómo podría desentrañar el cómo interactúa el código? De antemano, muchas gracias.

La forma en que obtengo los FPS los obtuve de la propia web de python-mss, y proponen dos, aunque casi me da los mismos resultados y varían unos cuantos FPS, no sé si me habré equivocado.

Comment: Falta algo más de contexto para poder responderte. ¿Qué framework estás usando? ¿A qué te refieres con "invocarlo desde el mismo archivo" frente a "invocarlo desde otro archivo"? ¿Puedes poner el código con que realmente lo invocas en cada caso? Porque a menudo la clave está en los detalles...

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Edité la publicación, no sé si ayude un poco más. Con respecto a algún framework, de momento no estoy utilizando ninguno.

Comment: y de donde viene `mss`??

Comment: No estoy lo suficientemente claro con los conceptos, pero si te refieres a python-mss(), [enlace](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/), me refiero a que sería el único y no hay otro adicional que haya introducido en esta prueba que hice. El sistema operativo sobre el cual está corriendo es GNU/Linux.

Comment: Siguen faltando detalles. No habías mencionado por ejemplo que estabas usando la librería python-mss, y no me queda claro cómo por ejemplo calculas los FPS (si los mides mediante código adicional, éste puede estar influyendo en el resultado). Por otro lado no tiene sentido (a priori) que llamando a la función desde dentro del propio código te salga un rendimiento peor que llamando a la que está en otro módulo. Creo que aún necesito ver los detalles de cómo lo haces en cada uno de los dos casos, me refiero al código completo.

Comment: Lo volví a modificar agregando todo el código.

Comment: El segundo ejemplo creo que calcula mal los fps. No veo que se actualice la variable `loop_time` dentro del bucle. Eso causaría un número de fps mucho más bajo del real. Es posible que tengas también algún error en el cálculo de los fps cuando haces el `from test2 import Capturador`, pues el código de ese caso creo que no has mostrado.

Comment: Mis disculpas, en el segundo ejemplo la variable loop_time no lo había copiado, pero estaba. Respecto al caso de `from test2 import Capturador`, en main.py se mantiene el mismo código, solo que se habilita la línea `cap = Capturador()` y se modifica en `img = capturar()` por `img = cap.capturador()`. En test2.py  debajo de `if __name __ == '__main__'` sólo queda `Capturador()`, el resto se elimina. De hecho, el cálculo de los fps los elimino de test.py y test2.py y sólo queda en main.py. Acabo de editar el post a ver si ahora queda más claro el cómo lo estoy haciendo. Gracias por la paciencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que, debido a la variedad de pruebas que has estado haciendo y a que quizás no has hecho lo mismo en todas ellas de forma consistente, (por ejemplo editabas el código para eliminar partes antes de la siguiente prueba) has acabado ejecutando cosas no comparables entre sí y por tanto con esos resultados incomprensibles.

Todo lo que puedo decir es que a mi sí me salen resultados consistentes. Te voy a poner exactamente el código que he usado para que puedas utilizar tú este mismo código en tus pruebas y verifiques que con él también obtienes resultados consistentes.

Para mis pruebas he usado cinco ficheros .py que son:

- `test.py` contiene un bucle que se ejecuta 100 veces para hacer 100 capturas de pantalla y calcular las FPS de cada captura (la inversa del tiempo necesario en cada una).
- `funcion.py` contiene una función que hace una sola captura. Además, llama a esa función 100 veces y mide los FPS de cada llamada.
- `test_funcion.py` importa la función que hay en `funcion.py` y la llama 100 veces midiendo los FPS de cada llamada.
- `clase.py` implementa una clase `Capturador` que tiene un método `capturador()`. Además instancia una vez esa clase y luego llama 100 veces a su método para medir las FPS de cada llamada.
- `test_clase.py` importa la clase de `clase.py`, la instancia, y ejecuta 100 veces en un bucle su método `.capturador()` para medir los FPS de cada llamada.

Estos son los códigos:

### test.py

```py
from time import time
from mss import mss
from numpy import asarray

lista = []
loop_time = time()
sct = mss()
for _ in range(100):
    sct_img = sct.grab(sct.monitors[1])
    sct_img = asarray(sct_img)
    lista.append(1 / (time() - loop_time))
    loop_time = time()

print(lista)
print(sum(lista)/len(lista))
```

Como ves imprimo la lista con los 100 valores, además del promedio que me sale de 11.75 fps. Es muy bajo porque lo estoy probando en un Mac un poco antiguo con pantalla retina, y por tanto con muy alta resolución. Debido a temas de permisos los mac son bastante lentos haciendo capturas de pantalla, y más a esa resolución.

### funcion.py

```py
from time import time
from mss import mss
from numpy import asarray


def capturar():
    with mss() as sct:
        sct_img = sct.grab(sct.monitors[1])
    return asarray(sct_img)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lista = []
    loop_time = time()
    for _ in range(100):
        img = capturar()
        lista.append(1 / (time() - loop_time))
        loop_time = time()
    print(lista)
    print(sum(lista)/len(lista))
```

En este caso me salen 11.37fps. Un poco más bajo (como cabe esperar porque estoy invocando al contexto `mss()` en cada llamada a la función, en lugar de hacerlo una sola vez antes del bucle como hacía en `test.py`).

Observa que la parte que ejecuta 100 veces está dentro de un `if __name__ ...` esto es para que se ejecute si desde línea de comandos haces `python funcion.py` pero no se ejecute si haces `import funcion` desde otro módulo (como de hecho vamos a hacer luego). De ese modo no es necesario andar tocando el fuente para quitar el bucle de test.

### test_funcion.py

```py
from time import time
from funcion import capturar

lista = []
loop_time = time()
for _ in range(100):
    img = capturar()
    lista.append(1 / (time() - loop_time))
    loop_time = time()
print(lista)
print(sum(lista)/len(lista))
```

Aquí me salen 11.26 fps, prácticamente lo mismo que cuando llamaba a la función desde el programa principal. En otras palabras, importarla desde otro módulo no tiene impacto en el rendimiento.

### clase.py

```py
from time import time
from mss import mss
from numpy import asarray

class Capturador:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sct = mss()

    def capturador(self):
        image = self.sct.grab(self.sct.monitors[0])
        return asarray(image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cap = Capturador()
    lista = []
    loop_time = time()
    for _ in range(100):
        sct_img = cap.capturador()
        lista.append(1 / (time() - loop_time))
        loop_time = time()
    print(lista)
    print(sum(lista)/len(lista))
```

**DETALLE IMPORTANTE**. He quitado del código la parte en que asignabas manualmente la resolución de la pantalla. Para que el código sea comparable al del caso "función", lo he cambiado por una referencia a `self.sct.monitors[0]`, que usa la resolución por defecto del primer monitor.

Me salen 11.47 fps. Ligeramente más alto que en el caso de la función, pero de nuevo tiene sentido ya que en la función se invocaba `mss()` en cada captura, pero en la clase no (se ejecuta una sola vez al instanciar la clase y luego ya se usa `self.sct` en cada captura).

### test_clase.py

```py
from time import time
from clase import Capturador

cap = Capturador()
lista = []
loop_time = time()
for _ in range(100):
    sct_img = cap.capturador()
    lista.append(1 / (time() - loop_time))
    loop_time = time()
print(lista)
print(sum(lista)/len(lista))
```

Me salen 11.41 fps, prácticamente lo mismo que en el caso anterior. Es decir, el importar la clase desde otro módulo no incurre en penalización.

### Gráficas de resultados

Aprovechando que he volcado las listas con los fps de cada una de las 100 capturas del bucle, puedo usar pandas para hacer un plot de esos datos, y ver esto:

[image: Grafica]

Como ves, hay un cierto "ruido" (no todas las capturas de pantalla tardan lo mismo), pero todas mis medidas oscilan en torno a los 11FPS sin que importe mucho el método usado.

Otra forma de ver los resultados es usar un "boxplot" que representa en una sola caja para cada caso las 100 medidas:

[image: boxplot]

Las cajas azules marcan la zona en que se mueven los resultados más frecuentes. Fuera de esa caja aparecen los "outliers" (medidas atípicas). Estas medidas atípicas corresponden normalmente a las primeras capturas de pantalla que por alguna razón son más lentas (cargas de DLLs?), pero en cuanto se han hecho unas 10 capturas los tiempos se estabilizan.

### Discusión de los resultados

Vemos que aunque todos son bastante similares el test directo hecho en primer lugar es el que da FPS un poco más altos. La implementación en forma de función sería un poco más lenta debido a que hay que llamar a `mss()` dentro de cada captura de pantalla. La implementación en una clase de nuevo es un poco más rápida al evitar eso.

### ¿Por qué pueden salirte resultados muy dispares?

Creo que la principal razón sería que en unos casos usabas `monitors[0]`, mientras que en otros asignabas "a mano" las coordenadas del rectángulo a capturar. Cuanto más pequeño es el rectángulo a capturar, más rápida será la captura. De hecho a mi al principio las capturas hechas con la clase `Capturador` me salían el doble de rápidas que las hechas con la función, hasta que me di cuenta del detalle de `monitors[0]` y es que mi monitor tiene 2048x1152 pixeles, mientras que tu código usaba 1365x768.

También influye bastante en el rendimiento qué esté sucediendo en la pantalla mientras se ejecuta el programa. En mi caso yo no hacía nada, salvo esperar a que el programa terminara. Si en cambio mientras se ejecutaba me ponía a navegar por internet u otras cosas, las FPS bajaban.

Por ejemplo, ejecutando `test.py` (el más rápido de los cinco casos) mientras usaba el navegador, las fps bajaron a 9.8 en promedio, y se volvieron mucho más inestables como muestra la gráfica:

[image: Mientras usaba el navegador]

Comment: A mi también parece que lo lógico y consistente sería que los resultados debieran ser similares, o al menos dentro del mismo rango ya que al importar, agrega más código y está llamando fuera de, pero al copiar tu código y reproducirlo en mi computador... me sigue dando la misma incongruencia. Al importarlo me arroja 130 y al ejecutarlo desde el mismo archivo, pues me marca menos, al rededor de 90 y 100, que era lo que mencionaba con anterioridad. En síntesis, me es un completo misterio y hasta un absurdo y es razonable que disminuya puesto que hace uso de CPU. Gracias por responder, abulafia.